# How to create the configurable downloadable product in magento?

Tags: magento, configurable

I want to create a product with different attribute like color and size. when i will order product then this product will be available for download.

basically i want to create a configurable downloadable product in magento.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you have to set "links purchased separately" to "no" in the backend option for "Downloadable product".

I apologize I did see the request for screen shots, when creating a new downloadable product under the downloadable options tab you will see a selection for downloadable links to "no"

As soon as you do this, you will be able to see "Downloadable products" in the association list of "Configurable/grouped/bundle" products.

Then create your bundle/grouped products like you would with simple products

[image]

Good Luck!!

Comment: could you provide me steps with screen shots? I tried but downloadable product associate with grouped and bundle product. But I am unable to associate with configurable product.

Comment: AnyOne know how to create configurable downloadable product in magento. Please reply ASAP.